# wordpress htaccess url rewriting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to do the url rewrite for category list.How its done in wordpress using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

can you explain the question a bit more? Have you used the "wp_redirect" plugin? You can use the "regex" feature it provides to pretty much do all the redirects you like.